# Unwanted app crash by using SwipeableCardStack from wenchaojiang

Tags: crash

I wanted to add the AndroidSwipeableCardStack written by wenchaojiang. 
So I added everything like it is saidin the description but when I start the app it just crashes:

So it would be very nice if someone could help me:

This is my Layout File:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RealtiveLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/bildergalerie"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft ="16dp"
android:paddingRight ="16dp"
android:paddingTop = "16dp"
tools:context="com.example.felixjhn.info_tab.Bildergalerie">

<com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack
    android:id="@+id/card_stack"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />



</RealtiveLayout>
```

And this is my main class:

```
package com.example.felixjhn.info_tab;

 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

import com.wenchao.cardstack.CardStack;

```
public class Bildergalerie extends AppCompatActivity implements   
CardStack.CardEventListener {

private CardStack card_stack;
private CardActivity card_adpater;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bildergalerie);

    initImages();

    card_stack = (CardStack)findViewById(R.id.card_stack);
    card_stack.setContentResource(R.layout.card_layout);
    card_stack.setStackMargin(20);
    card_stack.setAdapter(card_adpater);

    card_stack.setListener(this);
}

private void initImages() {
    card_adpater = new CardActivity(getApplicationContext(),0);
    card_adpater.add(R.drawable.king);
    card_adpater.add(R.drawable.queen);
    card_adpater.add(R.drawable.king1);
    card_adpater.add(R.drawable.queen1);



}

@Override
public boolean swipeEnd(int i, float v) {
    return (v>300)?true:false;
}

@Override
public boolean swipeStart(int i, float v) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean swipeContinue(int i, float v, float v1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void discarded(int i, int i1) {

}

@Override
public void topCardTapped() {

}
}
```

And this is my CardActivity class:

```
  public class CardActivity extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

public CardActivity(Context context, int resource){
    super(context,resource);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_content);
imgView.setImageResource(getItem(position));
return convertView;
}
 }
```

Here I importet the repositories:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven{url"https://jitpack.io"}
```

And this is my build.gradle(module:app) file where I also added everything what is needed:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.felixjhn.info_tab"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"


 testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }

  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

//Add Library

compile 'com.github.wenchaojiang:AndroidSwipeableCardStack:0.1.0'
  }
```